# Should intern be called explicitly on every string occurence?

Tags: python, string-interning

Suppose I read a file line by line and save the lines to a list:

```
intern('abcd')
lst = []  
for line in f:
    lst.append(line)
```

and the file has five identical lines:

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

When the reading is completed, will there be five copies of 'abcd' in memory or just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be 5 copies. The `intern()` call *returns* the one copy of the string, it doesn't magically make all future strings with the same content interned.

I would *not* use interning for file data, however. The biggest advantage of interning strings is in performance-critical sections, where you need your dictionary lookups to be as fast as can be. Interning allows you to skip the equality test when pointer arithmetic can be used instead.

Interning has a performance penalty too; each time you call `intern()` the string is tested against an internal dictionary to see if the string was already interned. This requires a hash call and 0 or more equality tests (0 if the string wasn't interned before and there are no hash collisions, more than one in case there *are* collisions). Calling `intern()` for each and every line in a string is going to be slowed down by these operations, and only if you have a *massive* amount of repetition I don't think the memory gains will be all that great.

Comment: So in order to have one copy (after the garbage collection,say) I need to intern each string and append that to my list. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed edition, it does clarify the tradeoffs. In my case, there are massive repetitions though, which was the original reason for considering interning. Since there is almost no documentation, does the following summarize correctly what intern does: intern(S) returns an object, which behaves like a string S under  usual string operations, with the added benefit that such object MAY be unique and comparison between two such objects MAY be done by pointer. (the MAY part is because according to the docs, intern can also return just the regular copy of the string).

Comment: @komark: `intern()` looks up the string in a dictionary. It'll either find the interned copy and return that, or it won't find the string, thus it'll intern the exact object then return that object. It'll always return an interned value.

Comment: @komark: as long as your code continues to use only the interned strings, equal strings will be references to the same object. That means that any other source of strings (other files, user input, literals in the code) need to be interned too.